# I am writing simple node js api it giving me very unexpected error

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax-error, unexpected-token

Hello I am writing very simple api but unfortunately getting very unexpected error when i try to connect it says SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'

[image]

here is my code it's very random error

```
  const router = require("express").Router();
  const sql = require("mssql");

  router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  let username = req.body?.UserName;
    let password = req.body?.UserPassword;
   if (!username || !password) {
   res.status(400).json({ error: "Username or password is missing." });
   return;
 }
 try {
await sql.connect(
  "myconnection credentials hide it for stackoverflow"
);
// const result = await sql.query`select * from dbo.Users`;

sql.query(
  `SELECT * 
  FROM dbo.Users 
  WHERE (UserName = '${username}' AND UserPassword = '${password}');`,
  function (err, recordset) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).send("SERVER ERROR");
      return;
    }
    console.log(recordset.recordset);
    if (recordset.recordset.length > 0) {
      res
        .status(200)
        .json({ message: "Login Successfully", data: recordset.recordset });
      return;
    } else {
      res.status(400).json({ error: "user not found" });
      return;
    }
  }
  );
 } catch (err) {
 // ... error checks
  res.status(400).json({ error: "something went wrong" });
  console.log(err);
   return;
 }
});
```

Comment: What is nodejs version?

Answer (score 1):

For `?.` operator you need Node.js version 14 or later.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

For your own project, you can rewrite it "older way":

```
let username = req.body && req.body.UserName;
```

Also there is possibility to configure babel with some plugins to transpile code, if you need to use older Node.js version and newer syntax.